# How to implement dynamic network structure with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a dynamic network, which is able to change the network structure according to the input data. Here is an example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02799v3.pdf

I wonder it that possible to use TensorFlow to implement dynamic network?
I think we may need to use placeholder to control the network?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This was announced a few months after your question. This is a roundabout way to do that. I have heard other libraries like MxNet will support this too.

https://research.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-tensorflow-fold-deep.html

You might want to checkout DyeNet for true dynamic graphs.